# Reference the shopping cart items template

Tags: magento-1.7, layout, template, shopping-cart

I am trying to change the way the products are shown in the shopping cart, for bundle products. I have a template that will deal with that. So I have created a layout xml file where I reference the normal template, but when I try to open the shopping cart - it doesn't load and just downloads me some weird file.

Here's the code in the layout file:

```
<checkout_cart_index>
        <reference name="checkout.cart">
            <action method="addItemRender">
                <type>bundle</type>
                <block>quotationitemprice/bundle_sales_order_items_renderer</block>
                <template>company/quotationitemprice/bundle/sales/order/items/renderer.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </checkout_cart_index>
```

It works for the order overview, that's why I was wondering what's the problem here..

P.S. I put a simple `Mage::log('I am here')` in the beginning of the template, just to test, but it seems that it doesn't get in the template at all, since I don't get anything logged.

Comment: The weird file it downloads as you put it, are you sure that isn't the stack trace error displaying where the problem lies?

Comment: @GeoffJackson-zigojacko - The file is `unknown data type` and when I open it with Notepad++, it's empty...

Comment: Is the path `company/quotationitemprice/bundle/sales/order/items/renderer.phtml` definitely correct? (i.e the folder `company` sits in `app/design/frontend/package/theme/template`?

Comment: Omg, yes, the path was incorrect. It's just the other 2 things that I reference the template in the layout are about sales, and this one is for the checkout, so I got mistaken... I don't know when I will get used to the so important Magento path convention. :D

Comment: Ah great, glad that sorted it - added as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path to template file was incorrect as per the comments on the question...

Is the path `company/quotationitemprice/bundle/sales/order/items/renderer.phtml` definitely correct? (i.e the folder `company` sits in `app/design/frontend/package/theme/template`?

Should be `company/quotationitemprice/bundle/checkout/cart/item/renderer.phtml`.

Comment: The correct path is `company/quotationitemprice/bundle/checkout/cart/item/renderer.phtml`